# How to stop insertTablet writing data from automatically filling null value with 0 in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

For Version 0.12, I use java to call for IoTDB client to write data, and I execute “session.insertTablet” to do the writing operation. In a certain period of time, some fields have no data, and these data will be automatically filled with 0 values. Is there a way to make it not filled? I checked some possible solutions. If every time point is written separately, and only the fields with not-null data are allowed to be stored, seems like the schema efficiency will be relatively low. Anyone know a easier way?